Llamaindex TS SimpleDirectoryReader works locally but not on AWS EC2 server
I have a node express server setup for a llamaindex RAG system. Locally I'm able to generate a VectorIndexStore from a directory I've called ./data and run queries successfully. However, I've just cloned the repo onto my AWS EC2 server and even though it boots up successfully it seems that the SimpleDirectoryReader fails to be able access the files in the ./data directory even when I have the exact same files.
The error is different depending on the file type, but I assume this has to do with the library llamaindex is utilizing to read the documents.
If it's a PDF file I get this error:
Error reading file ./data/example.pdf: InvalidPDFException: Invalid PDF structure.
I uploaded a docx file as well and got this error:
Error reading file ./data/example.docx: Error: Corrupted zip: can't find end of central directory
For a little more context this is a snippet showing how the SimpleDirectoryReader is being implemented:
const directoryPath = "./data";
const directoryReader = new SimpleDirectoryReader();
const documents = await directoryReader.loadData({ directoryPath });

I thought maybe the -rw permissions were not allowing the node_module packages to do it's thing so as a test I updated the ./data directory permission to drwxrwxrwx and still no luck.
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated, hopefully I'm just missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.
